# How to use %d to auto automation read maltiple varible

Tags: python, pandas

I have many sets of data that need to be read into the same DataFrame
The variable names of each group of data are data_1 data_2 ... etc.

So I hope that the data can be read in with one line of instructions instead of input line by line
However, there seems to be something wrong with the characterization method. I have checked Google and have not seen similar problems, so I came up to ask you all, thank you.

And.. below is my try.

```
for i in range(40):
    test_frame.append([data_'%d'%(i)])
```

Comment: You should be using a `list` data structure, rather than storing in separate variables like `data_1, data_2, ...` etc

Comment: Are your sets of data in files (what format?) How are they stored?

Comment: Dynamic variable names is a terrible idea. Unsure of a true duplicate, but I think that the answer is [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/3545273)

Answer (score 0):

Been there, done that :)

since I don't know what's the type of data_x, I assume it is not a dataframe as you are using a list.

```
for i in range(40):
    test_frame = test_frame.append([data_'%d'%(i)])
```

If its a dataframe

```
for i in range(40):
    test_frame = test_frame.append(data_'%d'%(i))
```

Appending in pandas is not an in-place operation